# Odoo Create Model Programmatically and Add/Append to One2many Field

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

So I have a `Sale` model and `SaleLine` model. `Sale` model have a field `sale_line_ids` as `One2many` from `SaleLine` model.

Sale

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    _name = 'store.sale'
    _description = 'Store Sale'

    ...
    sale_line_ids = fields.One2many('store.sale_line', 'sale_id', string='Sale Lines')
    ...
```

Sale Line

```
class SaleLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'store.sale_line'
    _description = 'Store Sale Line'

    sale_id = fields.Many2one('store.sale', string='Sale Reference', ondelete='cascade', index=True)
    product_id = fields.Many2one('store.product', string='Product', required=True)
    quantity = fields.Integer(string='Quantity', required=True)
```

I want to create `SaleLine` model programmatically and add that model to `sale_line_ids` field. How can I do that?

Comment: It will be difficult. Are you sure you want to do that programmatically ? Is it an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) ?

Comment: Yes I know, because I can't do that with UI. This is just an example code.

Comment: I think you could do that using a intermediate model, like an `TransientModel` model, whre you relate the parent `Sale` with the `SaleLine` childs, then override the `create` method or in a button of  `TransientModel` model call `SaleLine` `create` method to asigne the proper `sale_id` to the childs. Thats what I understand for 'programmatically'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is what I actually want to implement. However, the model is immediately saved to a database. I need to create a `SaleLine` model using `env[].create({})` method.

```
self.env['store.sale_line'].create({
    'sale_id': rec.id,
    'product_id': id_from_another_model,
    'quantity': quantity_from_another_model,
})
```

After that, I need to commit in order to save the data in a database.

```
self.env.cr.commit()
```

**UPDATE**

The previous answer required record to store directly. The best answer to solve the problem is to create temporary record that only saved when user click the save button.

Syntax

```
(0, 0,  { values })
```

First create `sale_line` list

```
sale_line = []
for data in list_of_data:
    sale_line.append([0, 0, {
        'sale_id': data['sale_id'],
        'product_id': data['product_id'],
        'quantity': data['quantity'],
    }])
```

Assign `sale_line` list to `sale_line_ids` field

```
self.write({'sale_line_ids': sale_line})
```

And override the create method to commit the change

```
@api.model
def create(self, values):
    self.env.cr.commit() # This is the important part

    return super(Sale, self).create(values)
```

Comment: Commit records to the database by hand its a bad practice according to odoo documentation.

Comment: But right now that answer is working for my use case. I hope can find a better answer

Comment: Can you elaborate more your question, in which moment do you want to create a model{button action, cron execution, ...) What do you mean about "programmatically*?